# I can't figure out why the blockedWeekdays.split is not a function error is ocurring, even on my redux store i can see that the values are being updat

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

The console.log(blockedweekdays) is printing undefined but on the reduxstore i can see that the string of values is there.
This is my redux page:

This is the code in my component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import {
    fetchReservationBlockedDays,
    fetchReservationBlockedWeekdays,
  } from '../actions/reservationsActions';



const CustomDatePicker = ({ selectedDate, onDateChange, id}) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

      const reservationBlockedDays = useSelector((state) => state.reservationBlockedDays);
      const { blockedDays } = reservationBlockedDays;
    
      const reservationBlockedWeekDays = useSelector((state) => state.reservationBlockedWeekDays);
      const { blockedWeekdays } = reservationBlockedWeekDays;

      useEffect(() => {
        console.log('Calling fetchReservationBlockedDays and fetchReservationBlockedWeekdays');
        dispatch(fetchReservationBlockedDays(id));
        dispatch(fetchReservationBlockedWeekdays(id));
        console.log('Called fetchReservationBlockedDays and fetchReservationBlockedWeekdays');
      }, [dispatch, id]);

    const isBlocked = (date) => {
        console.log(blockedWeekdays)
        const day = date.getDay();
            const blockedWeekdayss = blockedWeekdays
            ? blockedWeekdays.split(',')
              .map((str) => parseInt(str.trim()))
              .filter((num) => !isNaN(num))
            : [];
        
      
        const isBlockedDay = Array.isArray(blockedDays) && blockedDays.some(
          (blockedDate) => blockedDate.getTime() === date.getTime()
        );
        const isBlockedWeekday = blockedWeekdayss.includes(day);
      
        return isBlockedDay || isBlockedWeekday;
      };
  
    return (
      <DatePickerWrapper>
        <DatePicker
          inline
          selected={selectedDate}
          onChange={onDateChange}
          filterDate={(date) => !isBlocked(date)}
          minDate={new Date()}
        />
      </DatePickerWrapper>
    );
  };

export default CustomDatePicker;
```

I tried verifying the redux store and tried to move the useEffect into the component as before it was outside.